# Task Scheduling with Windows8

Tags: php, laravel

I have created at artisan command called php artisan log:demo and every time I put this on console I execute corretly.

[image]

But I have a problem , I have Windows8 local and I don't know how to execute this command every minute.

I don't understand where I can put this expresion

```
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

I saw the documentation of Laravael about Task Scheduling.

I think that I need to create a scheduled task at the same operating system since control panel.

This is a possible solution for my question?

I send the code now , I have this in Kernel file

```
<?php namespace App\Console;
use Carbon;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel {

    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        '\App\Console\Commands\LogDemo'
    ];


    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('log:demo')->cron('* * * * *');  
    }


}
```

And the LogDemo with PHP

```
<?php namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Inspiring;
use App\Empresa;
class LogDemo extends Command {

    /**
     * The console command name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name = 'log:demo';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Display an inspiring quote';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $usr = new Empresa();
        $usr->nombre="Holas";
        $usr->save();
    }

}
```

Comment: the "expresion" is a cron job for *nix and will not work on windows. for windoes you use the task manager

Comment: Ok , I delete the other question in this I explain better.